# Ways to have a multilingual website without changing domains?

Tags: javascript, php, html, multilingual

Such example would be www.meetup.com
if you scroll all the way down to the footer, you can see a drop down box for languages. 
When a language is selected, the website content switches languages to the one the user selects.

What method is this. As the website does not switch to a subdomain such as test.com --> en.test.com.

Please be elaborate in your answers, as this may help others in need to find out.

like always, thank you

Comment: You could set session variables that pull relevant content. You can have URI segments that define this: www.something.com/en/somepage, etc.

Comment: You can also keep language choice in cookie like in www.meetup.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

meetup.com does a reload of the page after the selection is made and stores the MEETUP_LANGUAGE as a session cookie.

MEETUP_LANGUAGE = language=es&country=

There is no special method for this. Their code probably reads this cookie and loads the corresponding localized content.

Some other ways to determine the language for the user would be to get the language preference from the browser or HTTP request header. Or determine the locale of the client ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want a separate URL for each language. This is a vital SEO rule: you cannot have a single URL pointing to different contents, and neither have multiple URLs pointing to the same content.

So if the site you were talking about shows different languages under the same URL, it is really bad for SEO as search engines will only be able to index the page in one single language.

Either you have subdomains as you mentionned
example.com (english)
fr.example.com (french)
etc.

or URLs including the language like subdirectories:
http://example.com/
http://example.com/fr/
http://example.com/nl/

You can then of course retrieve the language from the URL/subdomain.

Here you can find the very useful Google's guidelines for multilingual sites: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192

If your site doesn't need to be indexed and you don't want to change the URLs based on the language (and now I will finally answer the question :-), then you could just store the selected language into the session.